# What should be the Meta Tag content URL for social sharing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js website and I am trying to get an image appear on social share on FB and LinkedIn - to no avail.

Here's my code snippet from the header tag of the index.js

```
<Head>
    <meta property="og:title" content={frontmatter.title} />
    <meta property="og:description" content={frontmatter.metaDesc} />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.datainterview.com/background-call-to-action.jpg" />
    <meta property='og:url' content='https://www.datainterview.com/'/>
    <link rel="icon" href="/brand/logo.png" />
</Head>
```

The background image of the page, background-call-to-action.jpg, is located in the public/ folder along with all other image assets. However, as you can see below from FB share, the share thumbnail isn't displaying the image. Any input on this will be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The image must be the right size for the platform you share it with. Try making it 1200px width by 630px height for FB. Be careful testing on Reddit and FB - it will cache your test image, and you can't control when it gets updated. There are hacks for FB to bust the cache. Your best bet is to make test URLs not used in the production site until you know it's good.